# Getting different results when running python code one line at a time vs the entire script

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm just beginning to code in python using pywinauto.  If I copy and past my code into the IDLE shell line by line, it works how I expect it too.  If I run the code all at once, it dies after a few lines.  I get the same result using Spyder and running the code one line at a time vs the whole thing.  I don't understand how this is possible.

Comment: Without sharing your code, nobody is going to be able to help you. Please look up how to ask a question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is possible, because line-by-line evaluation at the REPL prompt is not exactly the same as running a program. But you have to show us the code, what it produces, and what you expect. As your question stands you are asking us to imagine what you have written and then tell you where the problem is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.